# WebDAV in Windows Explorer: Problems if port is not 80?

Tags: windows-explorer, port, webdav, owncloud

I want to connect to an OwnCloud WebDAV drive. I tried

```
\\IP:25000\owncloud
```

and get asked for my credentials. But usually it doesn't accept my username and password despite the pair is entered correctly.
But - and that is strange - sometimes it works (oh really!). But even then it's crippling slow despite a fast server and connection.
For me it seems Windows Explorer has a Problem that my server cannot use port 80 for WebDAV. Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

Try this format:

```
\\IP@25000\owncloud
```